# when i startapp "article", and python manage.py runserver, and I do not know why "module 'article.admin' has no attribute 'site" this error happen?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I start up an app named "article" but and configure an import like this: from article import * in the setting configure file, then when I run `python manage.py runserver` the error ocuur like this `AttributeError: module 'article.admin' has no attribute 'site'`, when I comments `from article import *` with `#`, it will work on well, I do not know how `from article import *` raise the problem.

```py
    from article import *
    atterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^article/',include('article.urls',namespace='article')),
        ]
```

The output:

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\pythonTestfolder\xuegod\blogtest\blogtest\urls.py", line 25, in <module>
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
AttributeError: module 'article.admin' has no attribute 'site'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to import from your article app here
especially all of its contents with `*`

include method will work with a **string** of app_name and it's urls.py file , as you have wright corectly

and after that if it is a newer version of django project you are using , try not to use 
`url` method because it is going to be deprecated use `re_path()` instead , if you want to check for regex urls:

```py
from django.urls import path, re_path, include

urlpatterns = [
      path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
      re_path(r'^article/',include('article.urls',namespace='article')),
    ]
```

Comment: To explain a bit further, importing with `*` imports *everything* inside the article app; and one of the things in that app is an admin.py. So you have overwritten the name `admin` with that module, rather than the original admin site.

Comment: got it ,thank you very much,but one more to ask,where is the original admin site is,and what does the admin.py in the app work for?

Comment: admin is a built in module in django and it's location is `django.contrib.admin`and admin.py in any app's main use case is that you can register your created model in it and then access it from admin panel , and further more you can customize it's style and functionality in admin.py [django's doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/)